# Silverlight and the http code

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight application where wcf calls are failing.

I need to tell if I am receiving an http 500 error vs a 504 error.

Is there any way to capture this in silverlight so I can log it?

Comment: You need wrap errors by Wcf Faults and return via error contract back to a client proxy

Comment: you cannot wrap a 504 it does not reach the WCF.  The other question does not answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client Http stack will return 504 errors.

Answer (score 0):

You dont see 504 errors in your application because of a limitation in the browser stack. The browser will only return 200 or 404 to any plug-in (such as Silverlight).

You can solve this using [Fault Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx).

**[This article on SilverlightShow is essential reading](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Handling-service-exceptions-within-Silverlight-applications.aspx)** and will get you started